# How to return a class of subclass

Tags: scala, type-parameter

i like to define a factory method returning a Class-object, for example for creating gui objects.

I define a method like

```
def getWorkerClass2[T <: Component]():Class[T] = {return classOf[Frame]; }
```

which returns a subclass of the Component-Class, but the scala-compiler complains with

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Class[java.awt.Frame](classOf[java.awt.Frame])
 required: Class[T]
  def getWorkerClass2[T <: Component]():Class[T] = {return classOf[Frame]; }
                                                              ^
```

and i don't know why.

Edit:
I am using Scala 2.10

Answer (score 3):

Approach 1:

```
class C {
  def getWorkerClass2: Class[_ <: Component] = classOf[Frame]
}
```

Approach 2:

```
trait Worker {
  def getWorkerClass2: Class[_ <: Component]
}

class A extends Worker {
  def getWorkerClass2 = classOf[Frame]
}

class B extends Worker {
  def getWorkerClass2 = classOf[Window]
}
```

Comment: When trying to compile Approach 2, i get the same compile error like i got in my question:overriding method getWorkerClass2 in trait Worker of type [T <: java.awt.Component]=> Class[T];
 method getWorkerClass2 has incompatible type
    def getWorkerClass2[T <: Component]: Class[Frame] = classOf[Frame]
        ^

Comment: Oh, sorry, it seems I was mistaken when thought it'd work :) See my edited answer